# Control the execution in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

The below image contain `10 transaction controller` out of which the marked transaction `T03 and T04`, want to execute them every `two min once` but other transaction will suffice the general payload. How to do this is JMeter.

For example if I `run for 60 min test`, I want the `total transaction` for `T03` and `T04` should be between `30` and `40` [an arbitrary number but not more than this]

I tried to put `constant timer` as well as tried with `random think timer` as a child element for both the transaction with value with value between `1min 50s` and `2min`.

I tried with throughput controller by distribute the load as well. But not working with both the approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is running different Transaction Controllers with different throughput you cannot do this withing the bounds of a single Thread Group because due to JMeter's thread model it will wait for previous request completion before starting a new one therefore the overall throughput will be the throughput of the **slowest** transaction.

So you need to add one more [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and move your `T03` and `T04` transactions there

If you want to just reduce the number of executions of `T03` and `T04` transactions comparing to others - put them under [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and define either the total number of desired percentage of executions

If you need to pass some data between these Thread Groups - go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: Agree Dmitri, we need to move them to separate thread group

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if I have understood your scenario correctly or not, please try this.

Please detach the two transaction `T03` and `T04` with `1` thread to a separate thread group and run them with a timer which will pause them periodically ex: every `1 min` once.

This way the load on the other transaction will be as usual while this `T03` and `T04` will be controlled.